# Result suddenly wrong when running program on a big number of threads; threads getting called after WaitForMultipleObjects ends

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have an assignment to split a simple addition cycle (i++ 100000000 times, basically) into multiple threads and time them to see how the performance changes. My code works fine when the number of threads is below 100, but after 100 threads it starts producing completely bogus results. I tried printing the output of every thread to pinpoint the problem, and most of them returned 0. I then added an id parameter to each thread for them to print when they were called, and it turned out that once there were more than 100 threads some didn't get called at all, and some were called *after* WaitForMultipleObjects should have caught them. My guess would be that it times out, but it's set to INFINITE.

Here's the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

DWORD WINAPI fun(LPVOID lpParam);
typedef struct segm {
    int start;
    int stop;
    double res;
    int id;
}*PSEGM;

DWORD   thrID[500];
HANDLE  handles[500];
int m = 100000000;
int n;
double res;

int ns[25] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
              16,20,30,40,50,100,200,300,400,500 };

DWORD WINAPI fun(LPVOID lpParam) {
    PSEGM ps;
    ps = (PSEGM)lpParam;
    printf("%d ", ps->id);
    for (int i = ps->start; i < ps->stop; i++) {
        ps->res += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

struct segm sa[500];
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        n = ns[i];
        int step = m / n;
        res = 0;
        printf("\n\ni=%d; n=%d;", i,n);
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            sa[k].start = k * step + 1;
            sa[k].stop = (k + 1) * step;
            sa[k].res = 0;
            sa[k].id = k; 
        }
        sa[0].start = 0;
        sa[n - 1].stop = m;
       
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            handles[k] = CreateThread(NULL,0,fun, &sa[k],0,&thrID[k]);
            if (handles[k] == NULL){ ExitProcess(3);}
        }
        WaitForMultipleObjects(n, handles, TRUE, INFINITE);
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
            res += sa[k].res;
            CloseHandle(handles[k]);
            //printf("%d:%2.4f ", k, sa[k].res);
        }
        printf("total: ");
        cout << res;

    }    
}
```

An example of a normal and bogus output (I removed the timing stuff from the example for brevity):

```
i=19; n=50;0 1 2 3 6 5 8 4 7 12 16 14 20 18 25 26 9 10 11 13 15 17 34 19 36 22 23 38 27 40 41 42 43 44 33 35 45 37 24 47 28 48 30 31 49 32 21 46 39 29 time: 0.0410; total: 1e+08

i=20; n=100;0 3 4 1 5 6 7 9 2 8 10 13 12 20 14 15 11 18 21 16 17 37 19 41 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 34 35 39 74 75 time: 0.0280; total: 3.4e+0731 40 32 76 33 42 46 47 48 49 98 84 43 53 54 55 56 58 57 59
```

I am also getting these two warnings: `Using uninitialized memory 'handles[BYTE:0]'`  and `Buffer overrun while writing to 'sa'`. I don't see how I could have a buffer overrun; I tried making sa bigger, but the warning didn't go away. I think I've initialized everything, too. I don't know if these things are related to the error, though.

I'm really stuck and confused and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: OT: Why all the global variables? They are a bad habit.

Comment: Also OT: Doing C-style explicit conversions (*casting*) is also a bad habit. Use the C++ cast operators instead, as in `PSEGM ps = reinterpret_cast<PSEGM>(lpPAram);` On a somewhat related note, even though Windows itself defines type-aliases for pointers all over, I recommend you try not to. It usually makes the code harder to understand, and easier to do a mistake (like for example to use `sizeof(PSEGM)` when you want `sizeof(segm)`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They weren't global originally, my professor told me to change to global when I showed him this, haha) He said it's more efficient.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  could the casting details affect anything, or is it just a stylistic thing?

Comment: In every thread, you output the `id` field of the segment. The above code always sets that field to zero, still you get something like sequence numbers though. I'd say this isn't the code producing the output you presented.

Comment: Start with checking the return value of `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Fixed, sorry, messed it up while transferring to SO

Comment: Hint: Read the documentation of [`WaitForMultipleObjects `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) closely, especially the part about the nCount parameter.

Comment: My ***guess*** is that it's a buffering issue! When you run in a console or terminal, and the output is not piped or redirected, output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` is printing) is *line buffered*. That means output is actually written to the console or terminal when you print a newline, *or* the buffer is full, *or* the buffer is explicitly flushed (which happens when the program ends). Why are you using the old and type-unsafe `printf` function to begin with? As a possible check, do `fflush(stdout)` after `WaitForMultipleObjects` but before the loop, and see what happens.

Comment: Using global variables is not more efficient. It depends but it can often make codes significantly slower because the compiler may reload frequently the variables from memory (GCC often do that). On top of that, global variable can also introduce an additional overhead when they are fetched regarding the target platform. They are not good for performance nor for software engineering. The only usage which is fine is global constants. They can help to design quick prototypes (since there is no need to care about passing variables between functions which is the main issue).

Comment: @Jabberwocky "The number of object handles in the array pointed to by lpHandles" so am I going to have to reinitialize the handles array on every loop to match n? That seems awfully inefficient; also, why didn't it break on smaller thread counts?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude didn't work, unfortunately( I will try to switch it to cout, though, thanks

Comment: Your code assume `n * (m / n) == m` which is only true if `m | n` (i.e. `m/(float)n` is an integer), which is not true because `n = ns[i]` and `m = 100000000` and `ns[2] = 3` and `100000000 % 3` is not 0. Here, a wrong start-stop is not so critical (possibly just a wrong value for res), but it can cause buffer overflows if you use them for indexing arrays (quite frequent). You should not pre-compute `step` but compute `(k*m)/n` and `((k+1)*m)/n` directly. You should also be careful about having overflow. Using 64-bit integer help to avoid this issue.

Comment: By the way, note that functions like `CreateThread` are not portable (Windows-specific). You can do the same thing in OpenMP (which is portable and supported by all mainstream compilers). It is simpler and less bug-prone (and possibly faster regarding the OpenMP implementation). You just need to write a sequential loop and add `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:res) schedule(static, step)` where `res` is the variable being accumulated and `step` is the size of the chunks. No need for a separate function, nor globals, nor passing parameters, nor computing indices, etc.

Comment: Why do you even use the windows API for this? There is std::thread, std::condition_variable, std::mutex in C++ since C++11 there should be no need to to use the windows api

Comment: @JérômeRichard Why even use OMP, C++11 and later have threading support out of the box

Comment: @PepijnKramer While the C++11 threading support should be preferred over the WinAPI one, OpenMP is not just a threading library, but far more than that, and things are generally simpler than using a library due to the compiler integration. Doing a reduction and partitioning is bug prone (e.g. the code of the OP). Besides you can use a dynamic/guided scheduling by just changing `static` by `dynamic` or `guided`. Doing that efficiently in C++ is not so trivial. Here it is just 1 simple line ;) .

Comment: @PepijnKramer On top of that OpenMP supports tasks with data dependencies while C++ does not. Rewriting an efficient task scheduler with dependencies is particularly difficult, even for skilled developers (not to mention one need to care about scalability on many-cores architecture, SMT, NUMA effects, recursive tasks, possibly ones on accelerators like GPUs, etc.). It is also easy to bind threads to cores in OpenMP while this is tedious in C++ (and not so standard in practice).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the feedback, I must admit don't know much about OpenMP, sounds like most things using it or not is mostly a matter of requirements,  (I more used to controlling systems than doing a lot of dataprocessing/calcuations)  so that does kind of bias my views ;) (Anyway from experience almost anything is better than using the WinAPI directly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WaitForMultipleObjects` can only wait on a maximum of `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` (which is 64) handles. As soon as you try to wait on more handles which is the case in your code, the wait fails and therefore your output is garbage.

If you want to wait on more than MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, you need to figure out something else, maybe like dividing your handles in batches of at most MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles and waiting on each batch separately.

Change your code like this, run it and you'll see what happens:

```
    auto r = WaitForMultipleObjects(n, handles, TRUE, INFINITE);
    if (r != 0)
    {
      printf("WaitForMultipleObjects failed, last error = %d\N", GetLastError());
      return 3;
    }
```

Comment: "maybe like dividing your handles in batches of at most MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles and waiting on each batch separately." Simpler is just to call WaitForSingleObject `n` times.